# How to use Scrapy to collect data from different parts in a page?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm interested to select some data from pages like [this](http://destinytracker.com/destiny/overview/ps/bymuni). I wrote the following script to do it. The problem is that I selected 4 parts (crucible, titan, hunter, warlock), but the location of data for different pages is not the same. I'm not sure if my approach to select different parts is fine.

```
 def parse_country(self, response):

    hxs = scrapy.Selector(response)

    crucibleSummary = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="site-body"]/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]').xpath('.//text()').extract()
    crucibleSummaryData = [e.replace(',', '').replace('%', '').replace('\n', '').replace('Top', '').
                           replace('#', '').replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '').strip()
                           for e in crucibleSummary]
    crucibleSummaryData = filter(None, crucibleSummaryData)

    titan = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="site-body"]/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]').xpath('.//text()').extract()
    titanData = [e.replace(',', '').replace('%', '').replace('\n', '').replace('Top', '').replace('#', '').
                      replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '').strip() for e in titan]
    titanData = filter(None, titanData)

    warlock = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="site-body"]/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]').xpath('.//text()').extract()
    warlockData = [e.replace(',', '').replace('%', '').replace('\n', '').replace('Top', '').replace('#', '').
                      replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '').strip() for e in warlock]
    warlockData = filter(None, warlockData)

    hunter = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="site-body"]/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]').xpath('.//text()').extract()
    hunterData = [e.replace(',', '').replace('%', '').replace('\n', '').replace('Top', '').replace('#', '').
                      replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '').strip() for e in hunter]
    hunterData = filter(None, hunterData)


    item = DestinytrackerProfilesItem()
    data = crucibleSummaryData
    item['DTRscore'] = [float(data[1]),  float(data[2])]
    ....
```

Comment: Read about [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current XPath expressions are *really fragile* and not readable.

What if instead of relying on the relative locations of parent div elements and their positions, we would use the *block headings* - in case of Crucible, it might be:

```
//h2[. = 'Crucible Summary']/following::div[@class='stats-stat-list']
```

For Warlock and other characters, you can look for `strong` element text to contain a substring:

```
//div[@class = "character-details" and contains(.//strong, "Warlock")]
```

Comment: Instead of getting the whole block to text... speciy the paths to you items Solution is simple,  if you can recall scrapy's  Official docs and the first couple tutorials.. the quote one...  If you can set a path that all  "box"  Divs,  and then use  this new path in a for Loop..  All you would have to then do is get the corresponding path to each of the items....  Don't know why you chose to use XPath though...  I did it all and CSS. With that said, XPath will save you in countless scenarios so learning to use specials expat syntax like "following-sibling" or "preceding-sibling"